# Checkout-PHP-SDK and createOrder connection issue

Tags: php, paypal

Trying to implement the Checkout-PHP-SDK paypal API to createOrder JS call.As far as I understand I have to send the data from php file to js approval form. But I am getting an error when I press the "PayPal Pay" button.

The JS codes are like below :

```
 <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
    <script>
         function loadAsync(url, callback) {
                            var s = document.createElement('script');
                            s.setAttribute('src', url); s.onload = callback;
                            document.head.insertBefore(s, document.head.firstElementChild);
                            }
                            // Usage -- callback is inlined here, but could be a named function
                            loadAsync('https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQgUM6x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd&currency=USD&disable-funding=card', function() {
        paypal.Buttons({
            // Call your server to set up the transaction
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('https://example.com/TESTS.php', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    return orderData.id;
                });
            },
            // Call your server to finalize the transaction
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                return fetch('/demo/checkout/api/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
                    method: 'post'
                }).then(function(res) {
                    return res.json();
                }).then(function(orderData) {
                    //   (1) Recoverable INSTRUMENT_DECLINED -> call actions.restart()
                    //   (2) Other non-recoverable errors -> Show a failure message
                    //   (3) Successful transaction -> Show confirmation or thank you
                    // This example reads a v2/checkout/orders capture response, propagated from the server
                    // You could use a different API or structure for your 'orderData'
                    var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];
                    if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                        return actions.restart(); // Recoverable state, per:
                        // https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/
                    }
                    if (errorDetail) {
                        var msg = 'Sorry, your transaction could not be processed.';
                        if (errorDetail.description) msg += '\n\n' + errorDetail.description;
                        if (orderData.debug_id) msg += ' (' + orderData.debug_id + ')';
                        return alert(msg); // Show a failure message (try to avoid alerts in production environments)
                    }
                    // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                    console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
                    var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
                    alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');
                    // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                    // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                    // element.innerHTML = '';
                    // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                    // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
                });
            }

        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
    })  
    </script>
```

The php file is like this :

```
     <?php  
        
        use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCreateRequest;
        use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
        use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;
        use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersCaptureRequest;
        
        require __DIR__ . '/Checkout-PHP-SDK-develop/vendor/autoload.php';
        // Creating an environment
        $clientId = "AQgUM7x3URK1A-rcNIq56covuc0CYGv3pb5sYeL6-cqsO1HYV2CV6h4ur6BCly_1YYd3-UOMTNGtwQXd";
        $clientSecret = "EDm88hmcFd6arhd7vaJ6d9AWjIvCScR6E6s0eM3OKqwf1uZt0G0KlLNUXG057vesyXR4eYP3RKDLJBz8";
        
        $environment = new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
        $client = new PayPalHttpClient($environment);
        
        $request = new OrdersCreateRequest();
        $request->prefer('return=representation');
        $request->body = [
                             "intent" => "CAPTURE",
                             "purchase_units" => [[
                                 //"reference_id" => "test_ref_id1",
                                 "amount" => [
                                     "value" => "100.00",
                                     "currency_code" => "USD"
                                 ]
                             ]],
                             "application_context" => [
                                  "cancel_url" => "https://example.com/cancelled",
                                  "return_url" => "https://example.com/success"
                             ] 
                         ];
        try {
            $response = $client->execute($request);
            print_r($response);
        }catch (HttpException $ex) {
          // echo $ex->statusCode;
            print_r($ex->getMessage());
        }
   if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    
$od_id = $response->result->id;
//echo $od_id;
$request1 = new OrdersCaptureRequest($od_id);
$request1->prefer('return=representation');
try {
    // Call API with your client and get a response for your call
    $response1 = json_encode($client->execute($request1));
    return $response1;
     // If call returns body in response, you can get the deserialized version from the result attribute of the response
   return $request1;
}catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex->statusCode;
   // print_r($ex->getMessage());
}
}
```

Should I create, and catch the order in php file and then send it to JS? Actually is it the proper way to send the data? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

I have added `CAPTURE` method to the php file. and now it looks like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your routes (the create route, and the capture route) must return a response that is a JSON string, and no other text nor HTML. print_r is not suitable.

Comment: So at least let me know please whether CAPTURE is enough in php side and the only thing I should do is to print the result as a json ?

Comment: onApprove should call a capture route, which captures the order and returns the response as JSON.  Before returning the response, you can check for success and store `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id` which is the PayPal transaction ID.  Return the response regardless of success or failure.

Comment: The case is that I am unable to get that phase. I have added the error screenshot when I press the button, please see my  first message (edited and added the screenshot). It means I have some issues with output of php file ? Returning the the response as a json part is making all mess. I used json_decode but still no success.

Comment: Okay I have converted the output into json with the help of `json_encode` function. Now I need to pass order id to the onApprove, I beleive.

Comment: you need two routes. the create route should return the order id to createOrder.  the capture route should receive an id FROM onApprove, use it to capture the order, and return the response

Comment: did like you said, edited first post. check please php file how it looks like now. Still getting the error : `Error: Unexpected end of JSON input` . Unable to proccess when I press paypal button. getting this error.

Comment: What is the output of your createOrder route, `https://deals.az/TESTS.php` ? Apparently it is outputting something other than just JSON. Use your browser's Network tab, Request and see what's in the body. It must only be a JSON string.

Comment: Okay, found it and fixed it.. the reason was instead of using `return orderData.id;` it should be `return orderData.result.id;`. in that case it is able to find the id as according to the output of json.

Comment: It appears you do a create on every page load, then check for an id and do a capture, which does not make sense. Your capture route should not do a useless create before capturing.

Comment: And there should be no print_r statements or any other print/echo statements. Return JSON, and only JSON, including in error cases.

Comment: 1) how can I return json without using any echo/print function. may I use `return $somevariable` ? 
2) How can I prevent not to reproduce the `Create` method unless I capture the created order? may I send the order id via post in the URL (`return fetch('https://example.com/TESTS.php?id=' + data.result.id, {`  and make a statement in php file `if(isset($-POST['order_id']{...}`  in order to capture?  But don't know what to do to prevent reproducing new CAPTURE each time the webpage is accessed. What kind of logic can I use?

Comment: Output one line. A JSON string. That is all. All other outputs must be removed. You need a route that returns an object with an id that is an order ID, and you need a capture route that accepts an id as input (somehow) and returns an object that is a capture response. The create route should not capture an order, and the capture route should not create an order.

Comment: What I undestood - So each time when the user presses the paypal button I have to create local order id and store it in database. Then if user presses cancel and tries to press again the paypal button it shouldn't create new CREATE (as soon as the purchasing product is the same) but instead use last previous attempt. 

regarding the json output, I meant what is the function which can be used instead of `echo` ? I only know return, echo and print_r to return the json output. I am using `echo json_encode($response);` in order to make the access of json when the link is called.output is 1 line

Comment: You don't need to store or reuse order ids. Create them on demand. Use exactly 1 echo every time one of these routes is called. Remove all other print statements.

Comment: I have completed integration. Just curious if I change `intent = CAPTURE` to `intent = AUTHORIZE`  will it still work or for Authorization process we need different workflow ?

Comment: For intent=authorize this must be on the SDK line when loading it, and in the createOrder call itself obviously. From onApprove you will be calling an /authorize rather than a /capture endpoint.  The completed order will have an authorization id in `purchase_units[0].payments.authorizations[0].id`.  You have 29 to capture an authorization, which itself can fail if funds are not available.

Comment: I got it, but did not understand your statement : `which itself can fail if funds are not available` - implying that the authorized funds can be used by user anyway ? Then it becomes that it is not safe way to authorize. I thought when you authorize the order the amount is frozen an can not be used until it unfreezes.

Comment: Authorizations do not freeze funds. Typically credit card companies have an honor period of about 3 days, but even then captures can always fail.

Comment: That completely destroys my website working logic... I was intending to freeze the amount for example for some purchases (which has not met the requirement - for example minimum order quantity) until the I want it to be captured. Then how groupon  style websites were working then ? + I had such experience about the freezing amount, I have purchased one item and it showed up to 3 day as pending, and I tried to take that money out was not able and bank told me that amount can only be used once seller unfreeze (return) the amount.

Comment: As I mentioned, typically credit card companies have an authorization honor period of about 3 days. You can read about authorization and capture here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/authorization-honor/#link-paypalsauthorizationandhonorperiod